# htaccess and php_value include_path - Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required file

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to running a site on my local machine. 
I've started modifying the htaccess file, using XAMPP.

Here is the old setting

```
php_value include_path .:/home/sites/www.example.it/example.it/htdocs/conf/
```

and here the new one

```
php_value include_path .:/conf/
```

The error I receive

```
Warning: require_once(conf.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'conf.inc.php' (include_path='.:/conf/') in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\wapp\index.php on line 2
```

Line 2 of index.php

```
require_once("conf.inc.php");
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: undo your changes? if the error started AFTER you changed things, then obviously your changes broke it.

Comment: actual settings are for the online site. As I wrote I want to run that site on my machine, offline.

Answer (score 0):

Your include path needs to point to where your files are on your computer:

```
php_value include_path .:C:\webfiles\example.it\htdocs\conf
```